# Dart Completer.complete() results never resolve

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a function that returns a future which depends on the result of a callback to resolve:

```
   Future connectSocket(String email, String password, {Function onConnectCallback}) async {
    var completer = new Completer();
    print("Connecting...");
    var query = getQueryString(email, password);
    socketIO = await SocketIOManager().createInstance(SocketOptions(localDomainWindows, query: query));

    socketIO.on("loginError", (data) {
      print("Login err");
      _connected = false;
      connectedCallback();
      completer.complete(false);
    });

    socketIO.onConnect((data) {
      print("***CONNECTED***");
      _connected = true;
      completer.complete(true);
      connectedCallback();
    });
    socketIO.connect();
    return completer.future;
  }
```

I can see `***CONNECTED***` printed to the console, and my socket server acknowledges the connection, but the function `await`-ing the resolution never resumes, it just hangs.

```
    socketConnection.connectSocket(_email, _password)
    .then((success) {
     print("SUCCESS") // never gets printed
}
```

Comment: Can you call `completer.complete` after the print statement?

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot I moved the complete() call before the print statement and it worked... got me. If you wanna put it in an answer I'll mark it accepted lol

Comment: It was the ```connectedCallback();``` call blocking it somehow. It calls ```setState()``` in another component, I guess it was messing something up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only possible explanation for this is that some code in the callback is blocking your program from continuing because `Completer.complete` should otherwise always make the `future` complete.
If it is blocked, however, the event loop will never be able to call your code.

As a `bool` assignment should never be blocking (`_connected = true;`), the only part of your function that could be halting your program is `connectedCallack();`. If you remove or fix it, you should see your future complete.